# What happens when you scale down a Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: kubernetes

When you decrease the number of pods in a Kubernetes workload, I am assuming it is doing a soft kill. Does it start that process by stopping incoming connections? In an event-driven microservice environment, where container reads message from a queue. When I deploy, what happens to the message that are currently being processed. Does it stop taking messages from the queue?

Comment: [Pod Lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/) in the Kubernetes documentation has some discussion of this topic.

Answer (score 3):

> When you decrease the number of pods in a kubernetes workload, i am assuming it is doing a soft kill.

Yes, it does a *graceful termination*, so your pod get a `SIGTERM` signal, but it is up to you to implement this handling in the app, before the pod is killed after the configured *graceful termination period*, by default 30 seconds but can be configured with the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` field of the Pod.

> In an event-driven microservice environment, where container reads message from a queue. When i deploy, what happens to the message that are currently being processed. Does is stop taking messages from the queue?

As explained above, your app needs to implement the handling of the `SIGTERM` signal and e.g. stop consuming new messages from the queue. You also need to properly configure the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` so that messages can fully be processed before the pod is evicted.

A good explanation of this is [Kubernetes best practices: terminating with grace](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace)

> Does it start that process by stopping incoming connections?

Yes, your pod is removed from the `Kubernetes Endpoint` list, so it should work if you access your pods via Services.